# Django: show a ManyToManyField in a template?

Tags: django

I've got these models in my Django project:

```
class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
class Place(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    area = models.ManyToManyField(Area,related_name='area')
```

How can I show the Place's area name(s) in my template? Currently I have:

```
{% for place in places %}
    Name: {{ place.name }}, Area: {{ place.area}}
{% endfor %}
```

which gives:

```
Area: <django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x10435a3d0>
```

And `{{ place.area}}` is just blank. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Use *place.area.all* in the template
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

```
{% for place in places %}
    Name: {{ place.name }}<br/>
    Area: <br/>{% for area in place.area.all %}{{ area }}<br/>{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Correction: Change **places**.area.all in line 3 to **place**.area.all

Answer (score 35):

You can use the existing join template tag.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#join

Here's the code

```
{% for place in places %}
    Name: {{ place.name }}, Area: {{ place.area.all|join:", " }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 9):

What does your view code look like?
Here's one way you can return the related models:

```
from myapp.models import Area, Place

def detail(request, place_id):
    place = Place.objects.get(pk=place_id)
    areas = place.area.all()

    return render_to_response('detail.html', {
        "place": place,
        "areas": areas,
    })
```

This example is just for illustration; you'd want to include error-handling code.
Your template might look something like this:

```
<h3>{{ place }}</h3>

{% if areas %}
  <ul>
  {% for area in areas %}
    <li>{{ area.name }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks! My problem is that I have another page with many Places in - so I can't easily calculate areas separately in the view for each one (question updated). Any ideas about what to do for this?

Answer (score 5):

For show only ManyToMany field:

```
{% for place in places.area.all %}
    {{ place.name }}
{% endfor %}
```