# Loop in ManyToMany Fields in django model

Tags: python, django

I have a model like this:

```
class MyProfile(models.Model):
      club = models.ManyToManyField(Club, default=None)
      city = models.ManyToManyField(City, default=None)
      .
      .
```

In view:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=id)
profile = MyProfile.objects.select_related().get(user=user)
```

With for example `profile.club.select_related()` I can find user's club. But I want do this in loop.

```
fileds = [car, club]
for f in fileds:
        print getattr(profile, f)
```

In the output I have `<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x9876545>`
But with `profile.club.select_related()` I can recieve user's club name. I cant use this query in loop. Is there any way to use such query for list of model fields?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: show a ManyToManyField in a template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270330/django-show-a-manytomanyfield-in-a-template)

Comment: this is not my question. I dont want show query in template. I want make query in decorator for use in a view. I want to make BULK QUERY.

Comment: That questions explains how to get actual info instead of `<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x9876545>`. No matter where, in view or in template.

Comment: @DrTyrsa , please give an example or link for bulk query! In loop I cant use profile.f.select_related() . What is the right way?

Comment: What do you want to get in result? List of profiles with a list of cars for each profile? Or something else?

Comment: I have 20 many to many field and I want make a bulk query for all fields in one loop like this: fileds = [car, club]
for f in fileds:
        print getattr(profile, f)

Comment: And what do you want to print actually? Can you show an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This fields are the same as "objects" field in MyProfile class. Adding .all() and casting it to list.

```
fields = [car, club]
for f in fields:
    z = getattr(profile, f)
    print list(z.all())
```