# ManytoMany field django template when models are in different apps

Tags: python, django, templates, many-to-many

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270330/django-show-a-manytomanyfield-in-a-template).
I have 2 models linked with m2m field and I want to render the field in template. How can I do this when my 2 models are in different apps:

```
apps/qapp/models

class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

apps/worksheets/models

class Place(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    area = models.ManyToManyField('qapp.Area',related_name='area')
```

Comment: Pls do: `areas = models.ManyToManyField('qapp.Area', related_name='places')` and being in different apps makes no difference with regard to a form field. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: ok, my bad, I was not using the related_name. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways we can show m2m fields data in template.

1. If you want to show all the places related to an area; see @Vitor's answer.
2. If you want to show all the areas related to a single place; see below -

queryset for the places `place1 = Place.objects.filter(id=1)`

Now in the **template**:

```
{% for place2 in place1 %}

    {% for area1 in place2.area.all %}

        <p>{{area1.name}}</p>

    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

I have deliberately taken variables like above so that someone new can understand where to put which variable.

Answer (score 4):

As schwobaseggl mentioned, that fact your models are in different apps doesn't make difference. Rendering fields connected via `ManyToMany` relationship should be pretty much the same.

If I understood correctly, the problem was that you wasn't using a `related_name`, and the code snippet you shared wasn't really your actual code.

But just for the sake of completeness, in case someone find this question in the future:

The use of `related_name` is not mandatory. If the `ManyToMany` relationship were defined as:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    # ...
    area = models.ManyToManyField('qapp.Area')
```

In a `Area` instance, you would be able to navigate like this:

```
area = Area.objects.get(pk=1)
places = area.place_set.all()
```

Because Django automatically adds a reverse relationship `%(model_name)_set`. If you set a `related_name`, it will override the default name.

Finally, to enhance the readability of the code, the relationship with the `Area` model would be better that way:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    areas = models.ManyToManyField('qapp.Area', related_name='places')
```

Using the plural form for the `ManyToMany` relationship. After all, it's a collection of `Area` and `Place` on both sides, so `areas` and `places`.

---

Now, to render a `ManyToMany` field in the template you could do it like this (considering your view returned an `Area` instance named `area`:

```
<h1>Currect area: {{ area.name }}</h1>
<h2>Places:</h2>
<ul>
  {% for place in area.places.all %}
    <p>{{ place.name }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: I was initially thinking that m2m field in different apps behave differently so I was confused. And you are right, the code snippet is just for reference. thank you for providing full explanation for the problem. On the side note, your tutorials are great.

Comment: I am able to get the M2M field's values on the template. Just not able to display the checkboxes alongwith each value **in a way to show them as multiple choice/s**. How do I do it?