# Display Manytomany

Tags: django, manytomanyfield

I have a little problem with a Django feature with the Manytomany. I explain myself I can add, to read the sobost stored in my manytomany. only downside when I try to display them, I can only in the console. I enclose my code so that you can enlighten me on the way that I should follow in order to successfully integrate them into my templates.

my manytomany is a little complex. I have tracks (playlist) that can contain several articles and each author can have several courses (playlist)

this is my Views.py:

```
def profil(request,id):
    parcour = []
    Myarticle = Article.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    All = Article.objects.all()
    UserProfil=User.objects.get(id=id)
    get_parcours = Parcours.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    for i in get_parcours:
        p = Parcours(id=int(i.id))
        article_in_parcours = p.articleList.all()
        parcour.append((p,article_in_parcours))
    print(parcour)
    return render(request, 'blog/profil.html',{
        'Article_by_author' : Myarticle,
        'All_article' : All,
        'Profil' : UserProfil,
        'Parcours_by_author' : get_parcours,
        'Article_in_parcours' : article_in_parcours
    })
```

This my template :

```
<h2>Mes parcours</h2>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  {% for i in Parcours_by_author %}

   <div class="col-4" style="border:solid 1px;">
      {% for item in parcour %}
        {{item}}
      {% endfor %}
   </div>

  {% empty %}
   <p>Aucun Parcours</p>
  {% endfor %}
 </div>
</div>
```

When i try to display parcour with a for loop, 
I have the number of div corresponding to the number of playlist, but they are all filled with the last content and not the one related to the playlist
Thanks in advance !

Comment: been few months since last time I touched `django` but you can take a look at this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270330/django-show-a-manytomanyfield-in-a-template` which looks quite right to me but I don't have `django` setup to give it a try.  Also if you have `related_name` for your model make sure that's really important because it defines the name you use to query

Comment: I saw variable in `template` not same name in `Views.py`. Example: you define 'Parcours_by_author' : get_parcours . First, try change `{% for i in get_parcours %}`  to `{% for i in Parcours_by_author %}` and check if have any change

Comment: Ngoc Pham i miss my code cuz i just change locals() to a dict and no it's change anything