# Question about model connections in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

There are two models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, help_text="Фамилия")
    second_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150, help_text="Имя")
    third_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150, help_text="Отчество")

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} {1} {2}'.format(self.first_name, self.second_name, self.third_name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('author-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Название книги")
    author = models.ManyToManyField('Author', help_text="Автор")
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4, help_text="Год издания")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('book-detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

On the page with information about the book I want to display its author, but what I do does not work:

```
  <p><strong>Автор:</strong> {{ book.author }}</p>
```

Also a problem with the author id. This line is broken:

```
{{ author.get_absolute_url }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access the author this method, because your book model related with author many to mamny relation. If you need really many to many relation you must change your template tag. You can see how to use template tag for many to many relation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4270839/7659834)