# django: Exception has occurred: IndexError pop from empty list

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have been building a website where each essay may have a video object. For some reason, this error in Django continues to persist and I cannot understand where it comes from and how to fix it.

The error related to **views.py**

```
Exception has occurred: IndexError
pop from empty list
  File "C:\foo\project\bar\views.py", line 65, in index_dev
    return render(
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

**views.py:**

```
def index_dev(request):

    essay = EssayCls.objects.all().order_by('-date')[:3]
    video_obj = VideoObject.objects.all()
    user_agent = get_user_agent(request)

    context = {
                'text_content': essay,
                'show_text_content': True,
                'video_obj': video_obj
                }
    if user_agent.is_pc:
        
        return render(
                    request,
                    'dev/index_page.html',
                    context
                    )
```

**models.py:**

```
...
from embed_video.fields import EmbedVideoField
...

class VideoObject(models.Model):

    video_item_url = EmbedVideoField()  # same like models.URLField()
    added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    title_video = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-added_date']


class EssayCls(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    organizer_email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    slug  = models.SlugField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(validators = [MinLengthValidator(10)])
    details = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    video = models.ForeignKey(VideoObject, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="video_obj")
    # video = models.ManyToManyField(VideoObject, blank=True, related_name="video_obj") # Many-to-many relationship
    language = models.ForeignKey(ProgLang, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL) 
    guest = models.ManyToManyField(SendMeMessage, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

**template.html:**

```
{% for essay_item in text_content %}
    <div class="contact-details">
        <h3><a href="{% url 'essay-path' slug %}" style="text-decoration: none; color: #35049080;">{{ title}}</a></h3>
        <p>{{ essay_item.description|convert_markdown|safe }}</p>
        <br /><br />
        <p>Does this video work? check below:</p>
                    
        {% comment %} {% for vid in video_obj %}
            <p>{% video vid.video_item_url %}</p>
        {% endfor %} {% endcomment %}

        {% if essay_item.video %}
            {% video %}
                {{ essay_item.video.video_item_url }}
            {% endvideo%}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm able to display all videos from **DB** everywhere (i.e. all videos from **DB** in every essay) with:

```
{% for vid in video_obj %}
    <p>{% video vid.video_item_url %}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But, even with `{% if video.video_item_url %}` I'm unable to display a particular video/s that is/are linked with one-to-many relationship to my `EssayCls` class. You can see my attempt in **template.html** (at the end):

```
{% if essay_item.video %}
   {% video %}
       {{ essay_item.video.video_item_url }}
   {% endvideo%}
{% endif %}
```

I thought that the error is related to the fact that not all essays have a video i.e. that the key for an essay that doesn't have a video is none/empty. So I did this Boolean comparison hoping it will fix it, but it doesn't. The error is the same with and without this comparison.

**UPDATE:**

At this point, I can access a particular essay(`dev/article-content_pc_tablet.html`) with connected videos by:

```
class MyEssaysView(View):
    
    def get(self, request, slug):

        user_agent = get_user_agent(request)
        selected_essay = EssayCls.objects.get(slug=slug)
        user_feedback = UserFeedback()

        context = {
                'essay_found': True,
                'essay_all': selected_essay,
                'post_tags': selected_essay.tags.all(),
                'form': user_feedback,
            }

        if request.method == 'GET':
            
            if user_agent.is_pc:        
                return render(
                            request,
                            'dev/article-content_pc_tablet.html',
                            context
                            )
```

**article-content_pc_tablet.html:**

```
<p>{% video essay_all.video.video_item_url %}</p>
```

As I said, this part works.

The difference between those two views and pages (the one with an error and another one that works) is the fact that in my class for a single essay `MyEssaysView` in **views.py** I have `selected_essay = EssayCls.objects.get(slug=slug)`. On the other hand in `index_dev` function, I have `essay = EssayCls.objects.all().order_by('-date')[:3]`. It is so because on my `index_dev` page I have several essays displayed from **model** `EssayCls`. I don't know how can I display adequate esay list on my "index page" with adequate video that is related to the particular essay from that list. All I understand from that error is the fact that the process tries to find those videos but has the wrong logic it hit an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this bug. Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4270839/15372196) and my own solution for [a similar issue I had](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75430878/15372196) in another template. There are a few bugs in the template's `for loop`.

First of all, I should choose `text_content` from context instead of `video_obj`. With that, I am able to display a particular video for a particular essay. Next, having a relation one-to-many I can simply loop that in the template using the proper syntax:

```
{% for vid in text_content %}
    <p>{% video vid.video.video_item_url %}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

But, in the meantime, I realized that it's a good idea to have the possibility to have several videos that can be added to several essays (*I added this part to the class `EssayCls` in my question: `# video = models.ManyToManyField(VideoObject, blank=True, related_name="video_obj") # Many-to-many relationship`). Having that in mind I needed to set up my main page in such a way that for each essay's div I needed to be able to display all videos from many-to-many relations.

To do that the proper syntax should include the chained part `.all` because the essay can have a query set of multiple videos that have to be handled. So I need to loop over text_content from `EssayCls` (which has a `video` column which is in many-to-many relation with `VideoObject`), after that I need to chain the iterator with the `video` column, then with `all` (because there may be more than one video) then with a link to a particular video from `VideoObject` class i.e. `video_item_url`  be:

```
{% for vid in text_content %}
    <p>{% video vid.video.all.video_item_url %}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Of course in this case the column `video = models.ForeignKey(VideoObject, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="video_obj")` in `EssayCls` class should be hashed or deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this?

```
{% if essay_item.video %}
   {% if essay_item.video.video_item_url %}
       {% video %}
           {{ essay_item.video.video_item_url }}
       {% endvideo%}
   {% else %}
       <p>No video</p>
   {% endif %}
{% else %}
   <p>No video</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work (the error is the same). I have updated my question with new details. I hope it gives more information that helps to solve this puzzle.