# Django template with forloop. Exception Type: IndexErrorm, Exception Value: pop from empty list

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a web page with essays. Each essay (on its own sub-page) can have multiple videos from another model (linked with many-to-many relations).

When I try to invoke a list of videos, with this new code:

```
<ul>
    {% for vid in essay_videos %}
            
         <li>{{ vid.video_item_url }}</li>
            
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I'm getting a list of URLs - that's ok, but, when I try to use the embed-video tag (like before):

```
<ul>
    {% for vid in essay_videos %}
            
        <li>{% video %}{{ vid.video_item_url }}{% endvideo %}</li>
            
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
    {% for vid in essay_videos %}
        {% video %}    
            <li>{{ vid.video_item_url }}</li>
        {% endvideo %}    
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
    {% video %}  
        {% for vid in essay_videos %}
          
            <li>{{ vid.video_item_url }}</li>
            
        {% endfor %}
    {% endvideo %}
</ul>
```

...In all cases, I've got *`Exception Type: IndexErrorm, Exception Value: pop from empty list`*

**My models.py:**

```
...
from embed_video.fields import EmbedVideoField
...

class VideoObject(models.Model):

    video_item_url = EmbedVideoField()  # same like models.URLField()
    added_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    title_video = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-added_date']


class EssayCls(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    organizer_email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
    slug  = models.SlugField(unique=True, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(validators = [MinLengthValidator(10)])
    details = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
    # video = models.ForeignKey(VideoObject, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="video_obj") # One-to-many relationship
    video = models.ManyToManyField(VideoObject, blank=True, related_name="video_obj") # Many-to-many relationship
    language = models.ForeignKey(ProgLang, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL) 
    guest = models.ManyToManyField(SendMeMessage, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
```

**My views.py:**

```
class MyEssaysView(View):
    
    def get(self, request, slug):
        user_agent = get_user_agent(request)
        selected_essay = EssayCls.objects.get(slug=slug)
        user_feedback = UserFeedback() # handling form submission 3.18.20 

        context = {
                'essay_found': True,
                'essay_all': selected_essay,
                'post_tags': selected_essay.tags.all(), 
                'comments': selected_essay.comments.all().order_by("-id"), 
                'essay_videos': selected_essay.video.all()
            }

        if request.method == 'GET':
            
            if user_agent.is_pc:        
                return render(
                            request,
                            'dev/article-content_pc_tablet.html',
                            context
                            )
```

How to solve it? The problem is with DTL syntax, or somewhere else (views/models)?

**EDIT:**

1. `{% video %}` tag is related to [embed-video library.](https://django-embed-video.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
2. The traceback of the exception:
   [image]

Comment: What's the `video` tag, and what's the traceback of the exception?

Comment: The traceback shows it's the video tag causing the error. Does the video tag expect arguments? You supply the argument `essay_videos.video.video_item_url` is one place, then don't give an argument where the error is being raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the syntax in **for loop**.

A proper way of defining a list of videos from the context provided by a class-based view that uses two models that have a relation many-to-many with [the embed-video library](https://django-embed-video.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is:

```
<ul>
    {% for vid in essay_videos %}

        <li>{% video vid.video_item_url %} </li>
          
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The rest of the code was fine.

Comment: I had a similar problem (fixed now) with another template. There I needed to display many essays on my home page and for each attached all related videos. https://stackoverflow.com/a/75466680/15372196 If someone has the same issue: how to display data from two models in many-to-many relation in one for-loop statement in a Django template, maybe this link would help.